# could not download pom file from https://search.maven.org/classic/remotecontent?filepath=organization/project/masterdata/master-data-core/2.99/

Tags: azure, maven, azure-pipelines

I am using Azure pipelines and i am frequently getting below warning and pipeline taking more time to finish

could not download pom file from https://search.maven.org/classic/remotecontent?filepath=organization/project/masterdata/master-data-core/2.99/master-data-core-2.99.pom GAV coordinates may not be in maven central

My POM file

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.masterdata</groupId>
<artifactId>master-data-core</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>MasterDataCore</name>
<description>Project Master Data Core</description>
<url>https://organazation.org/</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>organazation</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-masterdata-aggregator</artifactId>
    <version>3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springfox.swagger2.version>3.0.0</springfox.swagger2.version>
    <common.rest.version>1.33</common.rest.version>
    <version.project.security.client.util>1.53</version.project.security.client.util>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.swagger2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.swagger2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-clean-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.project.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-rest</artifactId>
        <version>${common.rest.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.project.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>security-client-util</artifactId>
        <version>${version.project.security.client.util}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
        <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.vincentrussell</groupId>
        <artifactId>sql-to-mongo-db-query-converter</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.pebbletemplates</groupId>
        <artifactId>pebble-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>PerfTests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>Drools</id>
                            <configuration>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*PT.java</include>
                                </includes>
                                <systemPropertyVariables>
                                    <implementation>drools</implementation>
                                </systemPropertyVariables>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project</id>
        <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/organazation/project/_packaging/project/maven/v1</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>project</id>
        <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/organazation/project/_packaging/project/maven/v1</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Comment: Can you confirm the location of the master-data-core-2.99.pom(In your feed resource or repo)? And where you define it in your project?